# Have any way to use application icon for notify icon?

Tags: c#, icons

I use same icon to set icon for my application and notify icon, but when compling, my exe file have two icon inside.

Have any way to set application icon to notify icon (or reverse)? I'm building tiny apps and reduce exe file size (even some kilobytes) is important for me.

Can you help me solve this problem? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want your `NotifyIcon` to have the same icon as your application, in your form do something like:

```
 trayIcon.Icon = new Icon(this.Icon, 40, 40); //trayIcon is your NotifyIcon
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the main icon of the .exe itself you can do it like this:

```
NotifyIcon.Icon = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your main form icon same as your application icon, and in the Form_Load set the icon property of NotifyIcon control to this.Icon.

Hope it helps

Comment: My application don't have title bar, and don't show icon in Taskbar, so I don't set the form icon. Is my problem is impossible to solve?

Comment: Hmm I don't think it is a problem.